# Can I be sure the page won't reload if I use `location.replace` to change hash?

Tags: javascript, hash, browser-history

I am using hash in order to avoid reloading the page (yeah, I know there's a new history API, but whatever...)

But now I want to change the hash without adding it to session History (i.e. don't want it in back button list), or add it removing the previous one. So what I don't want is having both the new one and old one in the list.

It seems I can use `location.replace`:

```
location.replace( location.href.replace(/#.+/, '') + '#' + newHash );
```

On Firefox 29 it works well and, since I have changed only the hash, the page isn't reloaded.

But does it work like this on all browsers (IE, I'm looking at you)?

Comment: Why not open your test page in said browsers and see for yourself?

Comment: You should be using `document.location.hash` to set the hash

Comment: @BrianGraham Because if possible, I want to avoid installing all browsers to avoid dirtying windows's registry, and therefore slowing the computer.

Comment: @Oriol: [browserling](https://browserling.com/) is free.

Comment: @adeneo Read better the part where I say "*But now I want to change the hash without adding it to session History (i.e. don't want it in back button list)*" :)

Comment: I did read it, and the same still applies, you should use document.location.hash for changing the hash, and then compare the url with the last url in History, and if they are equal pop of the last adress in History. Or you could rely on location.replace to not reload the page, which is what it really does, so there's are no guarantees.

Comment: I'm not seeing a page refresh in Chrome, you can type javascript: location.replace( location.href.replace(/#.+/, '') + '#' + newHash ); directly into the url bar to test via Chrome. Furthermore if you want to test in IE try this little tool http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Comment: @adeneo How can I pop the last address?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because of it being able to be solved by running a simple test.

Comment: @josh3736 Thanks for the link, I didn't know it, and I have also discovered browserstack. Both are amazing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing ([test page](http://jsfiddle.net/BsZmW/5/show)) with [browserling](https://browserling.com/) and [browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com/), it seems that

- No browser reloads the page
- Some browsers don't replace the last item in back button list.

Specifically, my code works on

- Firefox: 3
- IE: 6
- Chrome: 6 (but not on 5)
- Safari: 5.0.5 (but not on 4.0)
- Opera: 12.10 (but not on 11.6)

And, according to IETester, it works on IE 5.5 too.

**Edit** - The following code also works ([test page](http://jsfiddle.net/BsZmW/6/show)), with same browser support:

```
location.replace('#' + newHash);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can be sure. Why would the `replace` method do the same thing as setting `window.location` to a url?
If I were you, I would use `window.location.hash = "#newhash"`.

LE: Or just call `history.replaceState()`. It is the same as pushState, the only difference being that this method does not create a new history entry.

Comment: Because in general, `location.replace` loads a new page. And if I use `window.location.hash`, I add a new item to the back button list, and I don't want that.

Comment: Use `history.replaceState()` then.

Comment: But browser support for the new history API is poor

Comment: No, it isn't. http://caniuse.com/#search=history The only ones who don't support it are IE8 & IE 9, Opera mini and older Android browsers. And if you really want to support those too, use a polyfill: https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API

Comment: The polyfill you linked uses `location.replace` if `history.replaceState` is not available. Then, using that polyfill doesn't solve my question.